# Drupal 8 Webform - Pass submitted value from one webforms to another

Tags: webforms

I have two webforms on my Drupal 8 website. When a user submits the first webform, I have the confirmation redirect set to a second webform. I would like to populate one of the fields in the second webform with one of the submitted values from the first form. I have it set up as two separate webforms as some users will by-pass the first form and go directly to the second webform where they can manually enter the content into the field I need populated. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks

F

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I figured it out - for anyone else who comes across this question.

In the first Webform, I set the Confirmation URL to:

**/form/my-form2**?**value**=[webform_submission:values:**element_key**]

*I've bolded the elements in the URL that you will need to adjust for your webforms.*

This will result in redirecting the user from my first Webform to the second Webform (which is at the URL www.mydomain.com/form/my-form2) when they click the submit button. It will append ?value=[the value from the webform field] to the end of the URL.

Then in the second form in the field where I want this value to go, I have set the Default value for this field as

[current-page:query:**value**]

The word 'value' in the above can be anything, but it must match the id used in the URL from the first form.

And hey presto - it works!

F

Comment: You can simply use the webform setting *"Allow all elements to be populated using query string parameters"* so you don't have to set default values. I'd love to find a POST-based solution that doesn't expose submitted data in the URL, though.

Comment: For anyone trying to make this work in Drupal 7, the confirmation URL is slightly different: /form/my-form2?value=[submission:values:element_key]. Works great though, super simple.